# ¿Cómo implementar un Botón para "calcular" una selección de selects?

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando el siguiente script que encontré acá y funciona perfectamente para inputs. Ahora cuando yo le agrego valores desde **`selects`** si no agrego ningún número en un input y es todo **`select`** no me hace la suma, por lo que debo hacer al final de todo un input donde debo agregar el valor **`0`** y quisiera evitar esto.

Quisiera agregar un botón de ultima que diga **`Calcular`** y al hacer clic haga todo el cálculo.

> PD: Olvide mencionar que calculo 3 montos y las funciones en javascript tienen los nombres `sumar`, `sumar2` y `sumar3`.

```js
function sumar3() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".moto3").each(function() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      total += 0;
    } else {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('spTotal3').value = total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="moto3 form-control col-sm-12" onkeyup="sumar3();" >
        <option value="0">Sin Datos</option>
        <option value="500">1</option>
        <option value="1000">2</option>
        <option value="1500">3</option>
        <option value="2000">4</option>
</select>

<select class="moto3 form-control col-sm-12" onkeyup="sumar3();" >
        <option value="0">Sin Datos</option>
        <option value="500">1</option>
        <option value="1000">2</option>
        <option value="1500">3</option>
        <option value="2000">4</option>
</select>

<select class="moto3 form-control col-sm-12" onkeyup="sumar3();" >
        <option value="0">Sin Datos</option>
        <option value="500">1</option>
        <option value="1000">2</option>
        <option value="1500">3</option>
        <option value="2000">4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" class="moto3" onkeyup="sumar3();"  style="border: 1px solid black;"/ >

<input id="spTotal3" class="inputcentrado2"  name="total" placeholder="RESULTADO">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento que estas buscando es `onchange`.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function sumar3() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".moto3").each(function() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      total += 0;
    } else {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('spTotal3').value = total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="moto3 form-control col-sm-12" onchange="sumar3();" >
        <option value="0">Sin Datos</option>
        <option value="500">1</option>
        <option value="1000">2</option>
        <option value="1500">3</option>
        <option value="2000">4</option>
</select>

<select class="moto3 form-control col-sm-12" onchange="sumar3();" >
        <option value="0">Sin Datos</option>
        <option value="500">1</option>
        <option value="1000">2</option>
        <option value="1500">3</option>
        <option value="2000">4</option>
</select>

<select class="moto3 form-control col-sm-12" onchange="sumar3();" >
        <option value="0">Sin Datos</option>
        <option value="500">1</option>
        <option value="1000">2</option>
        <option value="1500">3</option>
        <option value="2000">4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" class="moto3" onkeyup="sumar3();"  style="border: 1px solid black;"/ >

<input id="spTotal3" class="inputcentrado2"  name="total" placeholder="RESULTADO">
```

Comment: Perfecto eso me re sirvio, ahora tengo otro problema tengo un select al seleccionar me da "valores".Este input no se suma hasta que seleccione otro select.

`<input type="hidden" id='costototal' value="Sin especificar" class="monto" onchange="sumar();"  />`

el javascript que hace esto es 

`var opciones = {

  "0": ["", "", "", "", "Sin especificar"],
  "1": ["1", "1", "tipo", "3000", "900"]
}
function cambioOpciones()
{
  var combo = document.getElementById('opciones');
  var opcion = combo.value; 
  document.getElementById('costototal').value = opciones[opcion][3];
}
`

Comment: Eso lo deberias plantear en otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

EL evento onkeyup funciona para input dónde puedas escribir, para el `select` es el evento onchange al hacer un cambio en sus valores, así te debería funcionar.

```js
function sumar3() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".moto3").each(function() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      total += 0;
    } else {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('spTotal3').value = total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="moto3 form-control col-sm-12" onchange="sumar3();" >
        <option value="0">Sin Datos</option>
        <option value="500">1</option>
        <option value="1000">2</option>
        <option value="1500">3</option>
        <option value="2000">4</option>
</select>

<select class="moto3 form-control col-sm-12" onchange="sumar3();" >
        <option value="0">Sin Datos</option>
        <option value="500">1</option>
        <option value="1000">2</option>
        <option value="1500">3</option>
        <option value="2000">4</option>
</select>

<select class="moto3 form-control col-sm-12" onchange="sumar3();" >
        <option value="0">Sin Datos</option>
        <option value="500">1</option>
        <option value="1000">2</option>
        <option value="1500">3</option>
        <option value="2000">4</option>
</select>

<input id="spTotal3" class="inputcentrado2"  name="total" placeholder="RESULTADO">
```